# Running Alteryx flows from command line

Tags: command-line, alteryx

I'm trying to figure out if I can launch a pre-built Alteryx workflow without launching the Designer - and without having Alteryx Server.
I came across a helpful post on Alteryx uses by @Runonthespot that, among other things, addressed running workflows from the command line, but doesn't go into detail. That discussion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469848/4313331. I don't have the rep to comment on his post and the question is closed.
He writes: 
"Flows are runnable from the commandline on a server, and easiest way I've found (besides using Alteryx's own scheduler) is to save as an "App", and then run from the command line using the Alteryx engine executable, passing it parameters via xml file. You can save a sample xml parameter file from your flow by hitting the magic wand button (after saving the flow as a .yxwz (app)) This brings up a panel that lets you set the variables, and that panel has a handy "save" button which generates an xml file in the right format."

So, I'm looking for more info on this process. Is it simply a question of using Alteryx Server? Or is this a more interesting work around?

Thanks.

Comment: For completely hands-free batch processing, you need Desktop Automation. This would cost less than Server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run a workflow (used generally to refer to a workflow, macro, or analytical app) without launching the Designer. You'll first need to understand how to run the workflow from the command line. The AlteryxEngineCmd.exe executable runs a workflow. It is located in the Alteryx install path in the bin subfolder. Here is where mine is located:

```
C:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin
```

It allows an additional parameter of an XML file with interface values. This is documented for analytical apps ONLY though it does work for macros as well. This is based on my extensive use of this undocumented feature.
Below are two examples:

```
AlteryxEngineCmd.exe MyWorkflow.yxmd
AlteryxEngineCmd.exe MyAnalyticApp.yxwz AppValues.xml
```

You can see a post here:
[Alteryx Command Line Help](https://help.alteryx.com/current/Command_Line.htm)

I prefer to wrap the command in a batch file and execute that for more control.

Now that you understand how to run the workflow from the command line, you can execute it anytime you want without launching Designer. Furthermore, you can use Windows Scheduler or a third-party tool to run the command or the batch file on a schedule.

Finally, you do need a license which enables API & Command Line w/ Scheduler. This is less expensive than Alteryx Server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried C:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe?  It doesn't require server.

https://help.alteryx.com/2019.1/Command_Line.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This option still requires a licensing option to run via API.

Comment: Your question was answered. If you're looking to completely avoid the additional licensing costs, that is a different question and wasn't part of your original post.

Answer (score 0):

If restrained by budget, you don't need a scheduler license (enables the AlteryxEnginecmd.exe), you can use a windows mouse clicker or even Powershell, to run the Designer though, without manual intervention.

Comment: Do you have an example of executing a model through Powershell? I am contemplating writing an AHK script to do this, but looking at non-GUI options.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to use Powershell without using AlteryxEngineCmd.exe. AutoHotKey would work though it has manifold downsides.